# DPI setting ignored on image

Tags: openxml, docx

I have a `.docx` document that I've been processing using OpenXML. One of the tasks I do is to replace and image by finding the size of it in the original document and generating a new one which *should* be sized correctly. However, in some cases it isn't. It seems that word wants to ignore my DPI setting and I can't figure out why.

Example, looking at the XML, I have an image with:

```
<wp:extent cx="4572000" cy="2971800" />
```

Converting EMU's to pixels with my desired `300` DPI, this should give me dimensions of `975` x `1500` pixels (that's `2971800 * 300 / 914400 = 975` and `4572000 * 300 / 914400 = 1500`). So I generate my image and push it into the document in place of the original. The image in the document should be `3.25" x 5"` However, when I load the resulting document and look at the "Size and Position" in word, it claims the image's original size is `10.16"` x `15.62"` and is scaled down to `32%` in both dimensions. The packaged image in the document is indeed the `975` x `1500` I wanted, but it seems that Word is treating it like it's `96` dpi (`975/10.16 = 96`). So my question is, why is it doing this and how do I stop it? I've explicitly set the DPI on the `BlipFill`, but it seems to be ignored.

Here's what the whole thing looks like in the XML document:

```
<w:drawing xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="1D5F6FCE" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
    <wp:extent cx="4572000" cy="2971800" />
    <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0" />
    <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 2" title="work" />
    <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
      <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1" />
    </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
    <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
      <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
        <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
          <pic:nvPicPr>
            <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 2" />
            <pic:cNvPicPr>
              <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1" />
            </pic:cNvPicPr>
          </pic:nvPicPr>
          <pic:blipFill dpi="300">
            <a:blip r:embed="rId13" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
              <a:extLst>
                <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                  <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" />
                </a:ext>
              </a:extLst>
            </a:blip>
            <a:srcRect />
            <a:stretch>
              <a:fillRect />
            </a:stretch>
          </pic:blipFill>
          <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
            <a:xfrm>
              <a:off x="0" y="0" />
              <a:ext cx="4572000" cy="2971800" />
            </a:xfrm>
            <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
              <a:avLst />
            </a:prstGeom>
            <a:noFill />
          </pic:spPr>
        </pic:pic>
      </a:graphicData>
    </a:graphic>
  </wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce the *original size* value you want, I believe you'll need to set the DPI value in the image binary to 300 dpi.

The `dpi` attribute on `<pic:blipFill>` you mention seems to be used by Word only during the printing process or perhaps if the image binary has no DPI value. In any case, it is not used to calculate the image display size in the document. It's quite possible that Word is preferring the dpi value stored in the image itself, if it's recorded there. That might be worth checking with an image viewer or whatever other means you have for that. In general, image dpi default is 72dpi. 96 is the system 'screen' dpi under Windows, which leads me to suspect that is the dpi embedded in the image binary, especially if it's generated by a Windows app.

As far as getting the image to appear at the right size in the document, it's the cx and cy values you want. If you set the ones in `<wp:extent/>` to the size you want, that should do the trick for screen display. However you'll also need to change the ones in pic:spPr/a:xfrm/a:ext if you want it to also print out at the correct size.

It sounds from your question like it actually appears at the right size, just that the *original size* reported in the Word dialog is not the expected value. I expect if you get the actual image dpi value set in the image you'll see the behavior you're after.

Comment: Thanks, after a little more research it did turn out that the images I was including had `96` dpi set and that's what it was picking up on. I copied the images to a new bitmap and set the dpi to `300` and that fixed the problem. The documentation on what the `dpi` attribute actually does is pretty poor and I couldn't find anything on the `useLocalDPI` attribute despite searching the whole 5,000+ page spec.